# GTK3 - Create image object from stock

Tags: gtk3

I want to create a grid which displays error message if the file does not exist:

```
/* size */
s = get_file_size(recording->filename);
if (s > 0) {
    size = g_format_size_full(s, G_FORMAT_SIZE_LONG_FORMAT);
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(size_lbl), size);
    gtk_widget_hide(error)
    g_free(size);
} else {
    size = g_strdup(_("Import Errors"));
    gtk_widget_show(error)
}
```

in gtk grid cannot set type of "error" element to display message as in screen shot:

```
grid = gtk_grid_new();
gtk_grid_set_row_spacing(GTK_GRID(grid), 6);
gtk_grid_set_column_spacing(GTK_GRID(grid), 15);
gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(grid), 6);

s_lbl = gtk_label_new(Size:);
size_lbl = gtk_label_new("");
error = ?
error_pixmap = gtk_image_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_DIALOG_ERROR, GTK_ICON_SIZE_SMALL_TOOLBAR);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(error), error_pixmap);

gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), s_lbl, 0, 0, 1, 1);
gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), error, 1, 0, 1, 1);
gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), size_lbl, 2, 0, 1, 1);
```

For any help, thanks.

Screen shot:

[Size]: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `GtkBox` with `GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL`, or an adjoining cell in the `GtkGrid`.

Comment: This question was tagged gtk3 but user938153 didn't indicate which revision of gtk3. If it's 3.2 or newer, gtk_hbox_new is deprecated. The documentation says to use gtk_box_new() with GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL instead. http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkHBox.html#gtk-hbox-new